# Android 2.2 SDK - System.out.println JSON string to long for LogCat?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

I'm getting a returned response that is too long for the window when printing to LogCat; even when I copy the line, pasting shows that the response is cut off.  How am I able to get the full string text?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was printing in a loop only 500 chars at once. Its not a good solution, but you should be able to get everything you need. Be careful with the side effect of slowing down your application, because printing thousands of chars can result in a massive slow down while the logging.

Answer (score 0):

What if you print it out before you make a JSON-object out of it?

I do it like this, using HttpURLConnection:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    sb.append(line);
```

Then do

```
Log.i("Appname", "Response: \n" + sb.toString());
```